# Adwords Scripts Search for 301 Redirects

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a question about catching a 301 redirects by using Google Adwords scripts. 
What I'm trying to filter is only the url-s that redirect to other domain, but not the ones that redirect for example from mysite.com to www.mysite.com.
Is there a way to do that?
I guess I have to use the UrlFetchApp method and then to compare the original url with the one returned in  the header.

Thanks :)

Comment: This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UrlFetchApp in combination with [getResponseCode()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getResponseCode())

```
 // The code below logs the HTTP status code from the response received
 // when fetching the Google home page.
 // It should be 200 if the request succeeded.
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
 Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
```

So in your case you can check if the response code is 301

Comment: That's right, 
but in this case when I have a url in my ad that points to (http)http://www.example.com and then it redirects to (https)https://www.example.com I get a 301 response. 
I'm trying to filter only the urls that are redirecting to other domains. Like www.example.com redirects to www.example1.com

Comment: As I don't have a page at hand with a 301 redirect I'm unable to test it for you, but I suppose you should be able to use [getHeaders()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getHeaders()) in which you should be able to check for both the response code and the page to which it will redirect.